# Render function of Zend Framework doesn't work

Tags: php, zend-framework, view, render

I want to use the `$view->render()` function of Zend Framework to include template parts, which are in a subfolder of the view script folder for the corresponding controller. It looks like this:

```
-> controller
-> -> TestController.php
-> views
-> -> scripts
-> -> -> test
-> -> -> -> index.phtml
-> -> -> -> -> layoutparts
-> -> -> -> -> -> button.phtml
```

And then i tried this in index.phtml:

```
$this->render('layoutparts/button.phtml');
```

but nothing happens and i can't figure out why.

Does anyone know, what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your action controller you need to return new ViewModel() and in view you can use partial helper.

So your view should contain code below:

```
<?= $this->partial('layoutparts/button.phtml'); ?>
```

[Check this link](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.partial.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it with the partial function, bit it is still not working. It seems that i don't use the correct path or something. I don't get any error, is just see nothing on the page.

Comment: Ok, now it works. I did a mistake with variable naming.
Thanks for your help!